# select values of multiple values of column into string variable as comma seperated in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to fetch data from a table Table1 in Oracle DB like this

```
ID       Name         TypeCode    
1         ABC        PRM ,USC,GSC
2         XYZ        PRM ,GSS
```

where TypeCode is comma separated values from another table.
Which is like this

```
TypeCode    TyoeDesc
PRM           SOME DESCRIPTION
USC           SOME DESCRIPTION
GSS           SOME TEXT
```

Comment: Please see [ask] in the help section. Following this as a template for your question significantly increases your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. Specifically here include the DDL for both tables, sample test data as text, the expected results from that data, and show what you have attempted so far.

Comment: How to map these two table?

Comment: Seems you shared your dataset missing, but evidently you need `listagg()` function with grouping by ID and Name columns.